Value of latitude, longitude varies on different network within same position
It's a web application. Developed on JavaScript for capturing client current latitude, longitude and php for calculation to verify client's current location data with specific latitude, longitude and radius value.
Problem is if I try with same position but different network , that time values of latitude, longitude become different.
I want to validate client on specific latitude, longitude with 100 meter radius area
Javascript
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, showError);

function showPosition(position) {

        var userPosition = {
            lat: position.coords.latitude,
            lng: position.coords.longitude,
        };

       // Sending data to php for validate
       $.ajax({.............. } )
  });

PHP
  $authorizedArea = [
        "lat" => 13.6666666,
        "lng" => 70.9997433,
        "radius" => 100 // meter value
    ];


    $userPosition = [
        "lat" => trim($request->get('lat')),
        "lng" => trim($request->get('lng'))
    ];


   $distance = $this->calculateDistance($userPosition['lat'], $userPosition['lng'], $authorizedArea['lat'], $authorizedArea['lng']);

   if ($distance <= $authorizedArea['radius']) {
          return 'Authorized'
    }

    function calculateDistance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2) {
    $earthRadius = 6371000; // in meters

    // Convert latitude and longitude from degrees to radians
    $latFrom = deg2rad($lat1);
    $lonFrom = deg2rad($lon1);
    $latTo = deg2rad($lat2);
    $lonTo = deg2rad($lon2);

    $latDelta = $latTo - $latFrom;
    $lonDelta = $lonTo - $lonFrom;

    $angle = 2 * asin(sqrt(pow(sin($latDelta / 2), 2) +
            cos($latFrom) * cos($latTo) * pow(sin($lonDelta / 2), 2)));

    // Calculate the distance in meters
    $distance = $angle * $earthRadius;

     return $distance; // return distance in meters
   }

I want more accurate solution to verify client current position based on defined  latitude, longitude and 100 meter radius.
Thanks in advance

Can you please be more specific about the problem. What do you mean by "different network" and can you give an example of such incorrect result? Did you try writing a unit test for your code?

I'm not sure geolocation is as accurate as you want it to be - mine says I'm about 65miles from where I am...

@ Gordon , different network means like mobile network , wifi ...... latitude in mobile network => 13.6666666  |  latitude in wifi network => 13.87654

@ fdomn-m, It's basically attendance purpose . How may I achieve goal ?

PCs (in general) don't have GPS details so the lat/lng is determined by your externally facing IP address - for a corporate network, this will likely be where your proxy/firewall connects to the internet (hence 65 miles away for me). Google and others drive around scanning IP addresses and their locations and store them in global databases that geolocation API uses.   See this SO answer from 2009

One of the options that you can provide to getCurrentPosition is enableHighAccuracy. If a device implements this, and if the user has granted that permission (where applicable), you might get better results. Also, the return coordinates object has an accuracy property that "the accuracy, with a 95% confidence level...expressed in meters". A quick test of my desktop computer gave an accuracy of 1073.9641428728814, which explains why it thinks I'm in a forest on an island in the middle of the Mississippi river.

The tl;dr is that you should not assume that getCurrentPosition() will give you absolutely accurate information. If you need more accuracy you might need to rely on native applications which have settings such as "Precise Location"

you actually cannot do this using network location on brower because these days dynamic Ip address is given by IPS which corresponds to different locations . best solutions is to make it mobile app based and  force use of gps hardware location from phone which will give accurate location.  these system is mainly used in employees attendance system . we have developed same app for employees which works only on mobile.

Or use a physical sign in system- e.g. the user has to tap a card (or their phone perhaps) on a reader in the building they are required to attend, in order to show they were present
